# Multiple google map not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

I need to enable two google map in web page. But only one map is working. I tried different ways to fix this but no luck. The strange thing is always work the first google map.This is my code.

```
function initialize() {
  initMap();
  initMap1();
}

function initMap() { 
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.511938,-2.134094);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 13,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map6 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map6"), myOptions);
};

function initMap1() { 
var latlng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(52.511938,-2.134094);
var myOptionsTwo = {
        zoom: 13,
        center: latlng2,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map8 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map8"), myOptionsTwo);
};
```

And I get this error message in my console. The second google map is always not working. First one only showing map.

[image]

I have put initialize at the end of API key

> API_KEY&callback=initialize

Is that wrong way to put that there or any other error?

Comment: do you want to add all markers in one map right?

Comment: it's not mandatory

Comment: Please check answer I have posted one example, I hope it will be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

**It will work for you.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
  <title>Google Maps Multiple Markers</title> 
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" 
          type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body>
<table border="2">
    <tr>
        <td><div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div></td>
        <td><div id="map2" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>



  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function (){
  initMap1();
  initMap2()
  });
   function initMap1(){
    var locations = [
      ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],

    ];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }
   }
   function initMap2(){
    var locations = [
     ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
      ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]

    ];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map2'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }
   }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```